# Primefaces: Picklist -> After some transfer, Target List is empty and sometimes both source and targetLists

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I load values in source on page load. But when I start transferring items from one to another, target Item list becomes empty in transfer in backing bean. sometimes it happens for source list too and both of them in backing bean are empty after couple of or a few transfers.

But on view, both boxes show the proper values.

For this transfer issue, I can't process the selected item lists. My Backing beans is of Request Scope. I am sharing with you picklist and Transfer method code.

There is a reference implemention here.

[http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/pickList.xhtml](http://Primefaces%20PickList%20Example)

My Pick List code:

```
    <p:pickList id="PojoPickList" value="#{mySampleBacking.myItems}" var="action" effect="bounce" itemValue="#{action}"
        itemLabel="#{action.description}" showSourceControls="true" showTargetControls="true" showCheckbox="false"
        showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" converter="entityConverter" >

        <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Available Menu</f:facet>
        <f:facet name="targetCaption">Selected Menu</f:facet>

    <!-- these events are available in 5.1.9 version. not in current 5.1 version -->

         <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{mySampleBacking.onTransfer}"
            update="msg PojoPickList2 displaymyItems myTargetCounter" />
      <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{mySampleBacking.onSelect}"
             />
        <p:ajax event="unselect" listener="#{mySampleBacking.onUnselect}"
            /> 
        <p:ajax event="reorder" listener="#{mySampleBacking.onReorder}"
             /> 

        <p:column style="width:25%">
            <h:outputText styleClass="ui-theme ui-theme-#{action.description}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="width:75%;" >
            <h:outputText value="#{action.description}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:pickList>
```

My Backing Bean Transfer Method Code:

```
public void onTransfer(TransferEvent event) {

    System.out.println("onTransfer...");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    System.out.println("event.getItems().size();::: " + event.getItems().size());

    for (final Object item : event.getItems()) {
        builder.append(((Menu) item).getName()).append("<br />");
    }

    System.out.println("myItems: getSource size: " + myItems.getSource().size());
    System.out.println("myItems: getSource size: " + myItems.getTarget().size());


}
```

Comment: hi! have you resolve the problem because I have similar issue and cannot find why it happens. tnx

Comment: Yes, reload the lists in init() with @PostConstruct annotation.